# Not able to access image from intent after close and open the application again (android)

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, android-permissions, android-gallery

I've been trying to build an app that is able to recover a photo from the gallery and use it in a recycler view with some content information previously registered.
I'm able to recover this photo normally, set it into the recycler view but when I close the app and open again, I receive the message saying that I don't have permission to access this content.

`java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{d5d38d1 7118:com.tods.docreminder/u0a169} (pid=7118, uid=10169) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs`

This is the way that I'm recovering the image from the gallery:

```
private fun configExternalStorageIntent(pathGallery: Int) {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.type = "image/*"
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select: "), pathGallery)
}
```

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val selectedImage = data.data
        try {
            when (requestCode) {
                content...
            }
            imageList.add(selectedImage.toString())
        } catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

And that is my manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"/>
    </intent>
</queries>
```

I'm saving the uri from the selected image and displaying it on another fragment. I register it on Fragment 2 and displays it on Fragment 1. I'm able to display it normally in the first time, but it crashes when I open the app again. This list is saved in room database. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance. If is there any information missing just tell me and I update it.

Comment: When your app opens a file for reading or writing, the system gives your app a URI permission grant for that file, which lasts until the user's device restarts. To preserve access to files across device restarts and create a better user experience, your app can "take" the persistable URI permission grant that the system offers. Look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions) for details.

Comment: Thanks!!! I was trying to do it properly and now it works!!